# Python pop and hex values

Tags: python, arrays

I’m new to python and really need some help. I’m opening a file in binary and looking for a specific offset then reading the first couple of bytes at the offset. I’m struggling to understand how I can further  isolate the value I need from within the returned string. So, I can correctly get a integer value of 21229 from the test file (which is hex value 0x52ed), but I need to take a step further and split the hex for only the first two bits (0x52), so that I get the integer value 84, which is the value I’m after. Code is below. Many thanks for any help given

```
offset=0x49f2
from array import *
import os,sys
def emptyarray(data):
    while len(data) > 0:
       data.pop()

bo=sys.byteorder
filename="c:\\test\test.fil"
fp=open (filename,"rb")
data=array("h")
fp.seek(offset,0)
if bo=="big":
   data.byteswap()
data.fromfile(fp,1)
value=data.pop()
print value
hexvalue=hex(value)
print hexvalue
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I guess nothing per se @alKid. It works, but I'm don't know enough python to get what I need; which is, in essence slicing the final hex value in two so I'm left with 0x52 (which in the integer that I need to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go from 0x52ed to 0x52 you can shift right by 8 bits:

```
>>> hex(0x52ed >> 8)
'0x52'
```

Comment: Cool..That's exactly what I need. Very many thanks @Janne Karila